# C++ How To Make Template Accept Certain Types

Tags: c++, templates, inheritance, types

I am making a entity component system, Where I can add a Object/Type to my entity:

```
template<typename ComponentType>
    void addComponent(){}
```

But with this approach, I can make any object and send it as a parameter and I dont want that. I want only certain types to be allowed, but more specifically, I want all the objects/types that extend Component to be allowed.
Note: that Component will be a base class for all other types that extend this.

Long story short how do I make this so I can only pass types to the template that are a child of this base class???

Is this possible?

Comment: [`is_base_of()`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/is_base_of) might be what you want (since C++11).

Comment: Since it's 2022, worth mentioning the concept form of it: `template<std::derived_from<Component> ComponentType>`